# IntelliTrace: why Step Over is disbled

Tags: visual-studio-2017, intellitrace

When I am trying to do "Activate Historical Debugging", the "Step Over" option is always disabled. I am using VS 2017 Enterprise.

I would like to do debugging through "IntelliTrace".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step Over/Step Into are only available in live debugging mode. You can press F5 to continue, the "Return to Living Debugging" in the info bar or the "Activate Live Debugging" from Events tab to switch to live debugging mode.
In Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Update 5, there are two more buttons, Step Backward and Step Forward, to navigate the events in the Events tab. That can achieve something similar to Step Over.